# Working Global Mouse (and optionally Keyboard) Hook with .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, hook

I'm trying to detect the horizontal scroll wheel movement globally in .net core 3.1 (or at least movement of any mouse wheel). I want to build this application to work for both, Windows 10 x64 and arm-linux. However, I only need the hook functionality on Windows. I have tried to use the [WindowsHook](https://github.com/topstarai/WindowsHook) which includes System.Windows.Forms MouseEvents and also the normal [MouseKeyHook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook) which it is based on. Both didn't work. The same goes for my implementations of [SetWindowsHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) and the [Raw Input API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input). Trying them in .net core applications only results in a massive input lag as soon as the listeners are in place and no events actually getting triggered. I searched for like two days now and I start to believe you need to be a wizard to get such a global hook to work in .net core. Help would be highly appreciated!

Edit: This is my first time working with hooks and doing low level stuff so I don't understand all of it 100%. I only have this code snippet here atm. For the WindowsHook and MouseKeyHook I just use the examples which you can find on corresponding linked github projects.

Here is the SetWindowsHookEx version, I just call the constructor to get it running and it doesn't even capture hscroll I believe:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Intercept_Mouse
{
    private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;


    public Intercept_Mouse()
    {
        _hookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, _proc, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
    }

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && (MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Clicked");
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }


    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

    private enum MouseMessages
    {
        WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
        WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
        WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
        WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
        WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
        WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public POINT pt;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint flags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

Comment: Help us help you by including the code you have tried.

Comment: Updated it, but it's not much :/